# Count past entries with similar key

Tags: r

I have this dataset which have a date and an ID. I can add a new column indicating how many entries with the similar ID exist, such as:

```
dataset1 = dataset1[,count_IDs := .N,by =  ID]
```

However, I'd like to count for each entry only those where the date of that row is bigger. Something like: count all entries where ID is the same and have the date <= the date of the current row, and add a column with that value.

```
ID | Date   | 
1  | 3/4/10 |
1  | 3/6/10 |
1  | 1/2/10 |
2  | 5/5/10 |
2  | 5/6/10 |
```

Result

```
ID | Date   | Other columns
1  | 3/4/10 | 1
1  | 3/6/10 | 2
1  | 1/2/10 | 0
2  | 5/5/10 | 0
2  | 5/6/10 | 1
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your expected output is not clear.  Why the value is 0 for 5/5/10 (ID 2) while it is 1 fior 3/4/10 (ID 1)

Comment: Yes, for 5/5 there is no other entry with same ID with a lower date. For 3/4 there is (1/2/10). It is not sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a self-join on your table, comparing each row to every other row in the group via `.EACHI`. Adding a row counter (`rn`) means you can exclude comparing the same row and affecting your results:

```
dat[, rn := .I ]
dat[dat, on="ID", sum(Date <= i.Date & i.rn != rn), .EACHI]

#   ID V1
#1:  1  1
#2:  1  2
#3:  1  0
#4:  2  0
#5:  2  1
```

Where `dat` was:

```
dat <- data.table(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2), Date = as.Date(c(14672, 
14674, 14611, 14734, 14735), origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm using Azure ML studio (CRAN 3.1.0) and get the message: unused argument (on = "ID")

Comment: @Shigaell - hmmm, I can confirm this works on R 3.4.2 and data.table 1.10.4.3. I've never used Azure, but I can only guess it is using old packages or not loading packages properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution. First I created a data frame from your data. Notice both are character type:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(magrittr)
> library(lubridate)
> df <- as.tibble(cbind(identifier,date=date))
> df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  identifier date  
  <chr>      <chr> 
1 1          3/4/10
2 1          3/6/10
3 1          1/2/10
4 2          5/5/10
5 2          5/6/10
```

I create a couple of intermediary columns with `mutate`, and then drop them in the end:

```
> df %>% group_by(identifier) %>% add_tally() %>% mutate(d=mdy(date)) %>% 
      mutate(timeorder=order(d < max(d))) %>% 
      mutate(numprev=n-timeorder) %>% select(identifier,date,numprev)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   identifier [2]
  identifier date   numprev
  <chr>      <chr>    <int>
1 1          3/4/10       1
2 1          3/6/10       2
3 1          1/2/10       0
4 2          5/5/10       0
5 2          5/6/10       1
```

You can see the intermediary steps by dropping the last `select`:

```
> df %>% group_by(identifier) %>% add_tally() %>% mutate(d=mdy(date)) %>%
      mutate(timeorder=order(d < max(d))) %>% mutate(numprev=n-timeorder)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   identifier [2]
  identifier date       n d          timeorder numprev
  <chr>      <chr>  <int> <date>         <int>   <int>
1 1          3/4/10     3 2010-03-04         2       1
2 1          3/6/10     3 2010-03-06         1       2
3 1          1/2/10     3 2010-01-02         3       0
4 2          5/5/10     2 2010-05-05         2       0
5 2          5/6/10     2 2010-05-06         1       1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm using Azure ML studio (CRAN 3.1.0) and get the message that add_tally function is unknown

Comment: Maybe there is another package that uses that name so you have to call package directly? Try `dplyr::add_tally()` -- here is the doc https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tally.html

Comment: Thanks again for your help mysteRious. I got this message now, I guess it has something to do with Azure ML studio and how it handles the packages, I think I saw others commenting on problems with dplyr   'add_tally' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'